# ITMS-90863: Apple silicon Macs support issue for HID_Approve_SDK.framework/HID_Approve_SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, hid, apple-developer

I have done HID implementation for HID. I've wrapped HID approve SDK in my application and using the HID functionality.

When i tried to build and publish the app in App store connect, then i got a error message from Apple App store connect like below.

ITMS-90863: Apple silicon Macs support issue

"Dear Developer,
We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "Test HID app". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

**ITMS-90863: Apple silicon Macs support issue** - The app links with libraries that are not present on Mac:

*@rpath/HID_Approve_SDK.framework/HID_Approve_SDK*

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect."

How to get rid of this error? Could someone pls help.

Comment: If this relates to Mac build, why have you tagged this question with [iOS]?

Comment: As I'm building app that is compatible to iOS, I thought it would have better to have iOS tag.

Comment: iOS and macOS or just iOS? Apple silicon Macs run macOS.

Comment: I'm building app for iOS mobile. Not for MacOS.

Comment: Then you are most likely submitting to the wrong App Store. Resubmit but to the correct App Store specifying iOS.

Comment: Check if you are supposed to mark the library as `Embed & Sign`. Your code is probably referencing it but it was not included.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was because the Runpath Search Paths (`LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS`) was empty. I cleared that build setting by mistake. I added `@executable_path/Frameworks` to the Runpath Search Paths, which was the right setting for my case, and I was able to submit the app to the App Store.